# Open or Create Directory from QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I need to create a dialog for selecting a log directory that allows either the selection of a directory or the creation of a directory if a name is typed in that doesn't exist.  I have been able to accomplish one or the other but not both at once.

With Accept mode `QFileDialog.AcceptOpen`, I can open directories.

With Accept mode  `QFileDialog.AcceptSave`, I can create directories, but I cannot open an existing directory.

Code Snippet:

```
def open_or_create_directory(self, log_dir):
    """
    open or create a directory
    Doesn't work!!!
    """

    dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self, caption='Data Log File Dir')
    dialog.setAcceptMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
    dialog.setDirectory(log_dir)
    dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
    dialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, True)
    dialog.setLabelText(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Accept, "Select")
    if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Accepted:
       logdir = dialog.selectedFiles()
```

The closest path I have been able to find is [QFileDialog: Selecting directories and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217120/qfiledialog-selecting-directories-and-files) but I don't know how to implement this in python.

Answer (score 1):

Surely what the OP points out depends on the native dialogue of the OS since in my desktop manager (plasma-KDE) it allows me to do both tasks, for example with one click it allows me to navigate in a directory and with double-click it allows the editing of the route, and with right click opens a menu where one of the options allows creating directories.

If the problem is with the native dialogue then you can use the custom Qt dialog to do so enable the option QFileDialog :: DontUseNativeDialog, in it you can navigate with a click and by right clicking a menu will open where one of the actions allows the option of create a new folder

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def open_or_create_directory(log_dir):
    """
    open or create a directory
    """

    dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(None, caption='Data Log File Dir')
    dialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
    dialog.setDirectory(log_dir)
    dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)
    dialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, True)
    dialog.setLabelText(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Accept, "Select")
    if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Accepted:
       logdir = dialog.selectedFiles()
       print(logdir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    open_or_create_directory("/path/of/directory")
```

If you consider the solution of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217120/qfiledialog-selecting-directories-and-files) to be correct then it is easy to translate it into python:

```
dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Directory)
dialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)

l = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView, "listView")
if l is not None:
    l.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
t = dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QTreeView)
if t is not None:
    t.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

nMode = dialog.exec_()
names = dialog.selectedFiles()
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, I'll try some of the suggestions and see if I can make headway.   In the native dialog (only tested on windows and osx) the right click option exists; however users have requested the simplified workflow of typing a name into the "filename" dialog box instead of taking the separate step of creating a directory and then selecting it.

Comment: @Tony You could explain in more detail the flow of the program according to your requirements since with what you indicate it can be interpreted in several ways. 1) What would be the procedure for a user to navigate between directories? I guess you want that when you click on a directory you must open the directory. Am I correct? 2) What is the procedure to create a folder? Maybe an outline or image helps you understand yourself better.

Comment: Our goal is to make it easy for the user to select or create a directory to store automatically generated files and directories.  I would like the workflow to be: 1:Select a menu item to open the file dialog.  2: Navigate to a directory for data storage.  3: either click on an existing directory or type the name of a new directory in to the "save as" field.  This is based on user feedback complaining about the extra step of creating a direcotry via the context menu and asking why they can't just type it into the text field in the file dialog